# Best option to upgrade Drupal 6 Video field to Drupal 7

Tags: 7, files

I'm trying to update a Drupal 6 site to Drupal 7.

I'm trying to move a video CCK field to Drupal 7. If I try to move to a video field, I get a message telling me there is not way to migrate.

How can I upgrade [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video) from 6.5.2 to Drupal 7.2.7?

Comment: which module are you trying to use to migrate your cck content from 6 to 7?

Comment: iStrikyer, I'm working with the standard migration module from cck.

I don't fine any way to move from video (6.x) to 7.x.


Also, I find a lot of problems with the database, video_tables, I fixed all the problems one by one.

Comment: In the url: admin/structure/content_migrate

Comment: Then idk. sorry.  I know content_migrate tries to do all cck work, but it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the video module there is no any direct migrate path even though it is CCK field, so what you have to do is use [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module. Just create a Views that output all the videos as XML in D6 site and use that XML input in D7 site to create new video nodes. This may need some additional effort but ultimately this will be really smooth approach.